# Pixi.js FocusableWidget example, to have an onfocus() event on sprite?

Tags: pixi.js, onfocus

We want to have an `onfocus()` event triggered on a Pixi's sprite, similar to the [`onfocus()` HTML event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp). I can see that Pixi has already a [`FocusableWidget`](https://pixijs.io/pixi-ui/PUXI.FocusableWidget.html) object and [`FocusController`](https://pixijs.io/pixi-ui/PUXI.FocusController.html), but there's not any example that can be found. Does anyone have an example, with a Pixi sprite?